# Why is java.lang.Integer.valueOf a flyweight pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Why is java.lang.Integer.valueOf a flyweight pattern?
I tried to find the reason but wasn't able to.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern + http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If we look at the source for `valueOf`, we can get a hint:
[Source of java.lang.Integer](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html) lines 638-643:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
        assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
        if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
             return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
         return new Integer(i);
}
```

It looks like the Integer class maintains a cache of Integer objects for common values.  Rather than make a new one every time somebody asks for `valueOf`, it just returns a reference to one that already exists.  Therefore, if you call `Integer.valueOf(1)` multiple times, you'll end up getting the same object back every time (not just equivalent objects).

Comment: This if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high) condition fails then it is creating a new object

Comment: This answer applies to the concrete implementation in the Sun VM. Technically the JavaDoc is what is relevant to this question.

Comment: So if you don't want to get cache, can you use `new Integer(1)`?

Comment: So from looking at the code here, it looks to me that you can change the size of the positive cache, by giving a value to `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>` during start up of the JVM. However you cannot alter the size of the negative cache.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like you have been asked to solve an exercise.

If you call the method twice with the same argument, it **may** return the same object thereby limiting the memory usage. This fits the definition of flyweight pattern.

Comment: The trick is behind Integercache.Is not it memory consuming in terms of flyweight ? I am good with the case where twwice with the same argument will return same object ,think of where i will provide different arguments and for every new call it's caching the objects.

Comment: If two different arguments are given, the result should of course be two different objects.

Comment: but my question is caching the object can lead you to memory consumption.

Comment: Correct, but there are solutions for that. Specifically a WeakReference http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html can in general be used to avoid wasting memory when caching this way.

Comment: Persueing this theme further, I found an article at:
https://javax0.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/hacking-the-integercache-in-java-9/
Which suggests that you can *hack* the IntegerCache class, to fill the cache with random numbers using reflection (even in Java 9+ by leveraging the `sun.misc.unsafe` module). I guess you could in theory use the same method to alter the `IntegerCache.low` field.